Nextjs: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__emotion_styles')
i execute new project, Nextjs, my problem is, after i add this two files i get this error i don't know why:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__emotion_styles')

ChatDropDown.tsx:
import React from 'react'
import Box from '@mui/material/Box'
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton'
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography'
import Menu from '@mui/material/Menu'
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem'
import SvgIcon from '@mui/material/SvgIcon'
import styled from '@emotion/styled'
import { useState } from 'react'
import Modal from '@components/Helpers/Modals/Modal'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { BiSolidMessageRoundedDetail } from 'react-icons/bi';
a

const ChatsDropDown = () => {
    const [anchorElUser, setAnchorElUser] = React.useState<null | HTMLElement>(null)
    const handleOpenUserMenu = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
        setAnchorElUser(event.currentTarget)
    }
    const router = useRouter()
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)



    return (
        <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 0 }}>
            <IconButton onClick={handleOpenUserMenu} sx={{ p: 0 }}>
                <IconSvg inheritViewBox>
                    <BiSolidMessageRoundedDetail />
                </IconSvg>
            </IconButton>
        </Box>
    )
}

const IconSvg = styled(SvgIcon)`
    font-size: 48px !important;
`

export default ChatsDropDown

MenuContent.tsx:
import { useRecoilValue } from 'recoil'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import LabelsAtom from '@atoms/Labels'
import { useCallback } from 'react'
import pages from '@constants/pages'
import React from 'react'
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react'
import { SessionData } from '@api/Models/Auth/types'
import ContentGenerator from './Components/ContentGenerator'
import { BaseParamsProps, MenuContentItem } from './Components/types'
import Notifications from './Components/Notifications'
import UserInfoProps from './Components/UserInfoProps'
import { ProfileInfoAtom, ProfileInfoLoadingAtom } from '@atoms/Auth'
import { Skeleton } from '@mui/material'
import MenuLogin from './Components/LoginMenu'
import MenuNotifications from './Components/NotificationsMenu'
import { ExhibitionMapAtomDialogAtom } from '@atoms/ExhibitionMap'
import { setRecoil } from '@admixltd/admix-component-library/RecoilNexus'
import ChatsDropDown from './Components/ChatsDropdown'

const MenuContent = () => {
    const router = useRouter()
    const { user } = (useSession().data as unknown as SessionData) ?? {}
    const authorized = user?.accessToken ?? ''
    const labels = useRecoilValue(LabelsAtom).layout.header
    const { profile, logout } = useRecoilValue(LabelsAtom).layout.header.userInfo
    const profileInfo = useRecoilValue(ProfileInfoAtom)
    const loading = useRecoilValue(ProfileInfoLoadingAtom)

    const baseParams = useCallback(
        ({ url, routerKey = 'asPath', condition = 'startsWith' }: BaseParamsProps) => {
            let active = false
            if (condition === 'equal') {
                active = (router[routerKey] === `${url}` ||
                    router[routerKey] === url) as unknown as boolean
            } else if (url && condition === 'startsWith') {
                active = router[routerKey].startsWith(url)
            }
            return {
                active,
            }
        },
        [router]
    )

    const LeftContent: MenuContentItem[] = [
        {
            title: 'Exhibitors',
            ...baseParams({ url: pages.dashboard.url, condition: 'equal' }),
            onClick: () => {
                router.push(`${pages.exhibitors.url}`)
            },
        },
        {
            title: 'Conference Room',
            ...baseParams({ url: pages.conferenceRoom.url, condition: 'equal' }),
            onClick: () => {
                router.push(`${pages.conferenceRoom.url}`)
            },
        },
        {
            title: 'Webinars',
            ...baseParams({ url: pages.dashboard.url, condition: 'equal' }),
            onClick: () => {
                router.push(`${pages.webinars.url}`)
            },
        },

        {
            title: 'About Us',
            ...baseParams({ url: pages.dashboard.url, condition: 'equal' }),
            onClick: () => {
                router.push(`${pages.AboutUs.url}`)
            },
        },
        {
            title: 'Contact Us',
            ...baseParams({ url: pages.dashboard.url, condition: 'equal' }),
            onClick: () => {
                router.push(`${pages.ContactUs.url}`)
            },
        },
    ]

    const RightContent: MenuContentItem[] = [
        // {
        //  component: () => <MenuNotifications />,
        // },
        {
            component: () => <MenuLogin />,
        },
        {
            component: () => <ChatsDropDown />,
        },
    ]

    return (
        <>
            <div>{ContentGenerator(LeftContent)}</div>
            <div>{ContentGenerator(RightContent)}</div>
        </>
    )
}

export default MenuContent

package.json:
{
    "name": "VirtualFairs-web",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "yarn svgo && next dev",
        "build": "next build && next export",
        "start": "next start",
        "svgo": "npx svgo --final-newline -q -r -f images/svg/"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@admixltd/admix-component-library": "^0.5.17",
        "@emotion/cache": "latest",
        "@emotion/react": "^11.11.4",
        "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.5",
        "@lottiefiles/react-lottie-player": "^3.5.3",
        "@mui/material": "^5.15.15",
        "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^6.0.0-alpha.18",
        "@mui/x-data-grid": "latest",
        "@mui/x-date-pickers": "5.0.13",
        "@svgr/webpack": "latest",
        "@tanstack/react-query": "^5.17.19",
        "@types/react-slick": "^0.23.13",
        "awesome-debounce-promise": "latest",
        "classnames": "latest",
        "cookies-next": "^4.1.0",
        "copy-to-clipboard": "latest",
        "dayjs": "latest",
        "emoji-picker-react": "^4.8.0",
        "firebase": "^10.8.1",
        "formik": "^2.4.5",
        "leaflet": "latest",
        "leaflet-geosearch": "latest",
        "material-ui-popup-state": "^5.1.0",
        "moment": "^2.30.1",
        "mui-modal-provider": "latest",
        "next": "latest",
        "next-auth": "latest",
        "next-http-proxy-middleware": "latest",
        "notistack": "latest",
        "nprogress": "latest",
        "pluralize": "latest",
        "polished": "latest",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-country-region-selector": "^3.6.1",
        "react-country-region-selector-material-ui-new": "^1.5.2",
        "react-detect-offline": "^2.4.5",
        "react-dom": "latest",
        "react-dropzone": "latest",
        "react-icons": "^5.1.0",
        "react-leaflet": "latest",
        "react-lottie": "^1.2.3",
        "react-number-format": "<5",
        "react-paginate": "^8.2.0",
        "react-phone-input-2": "^2.15.1",
        "react-player": "^2.14.1",
        "react-slick": "^0.29.0",
        "react-use-online-status": "^1.2.2",
        "react-verification-code-input": "^1.2.9",
        "react-video": "^1.5.3",
        "react-window": "latest",
        "recoil": "^0.7.7",
        "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
        "socket.io-client": "^4.7.4",
        "styled-components": "^6.1.8",
        "stylis-plugin-rtl": "latest",
        "video-react": "^0.16.0",
        "yup": "^1.3.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@tanstack/eslint-plugin-query": "^5.17.22",
        "@types/leaflet": "latest",
        "@types/node": "latest",
        "@types/nprogress": "latest",
        "@types/pluralize": "latest",
        "@types/react": "latest",
        "@types/react-dom": "latest",
        "@types/react-lottie": "^1.2.10",
        "@types/react-swipeable-views": "^0.13.2",
        "@types/react-swipeable-views-utils": "^0.13.4",
        "@types/stylis": "latest",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "latest",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "latest",
        "eslint": "latest",
        "eslint-config-airbnb": "latest",
        "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "latest",
        "eslint-config-next": "latest",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "latest",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "latest",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "latest",
        "file-loader": "latest",
        "intercept-stdout": "latest",
        "next-compose-plugins": "latest",
        "prettier": "latest",
        "react-swipeable-views": "^0.14.0",
        "react-swipeable-views-utils": "^0.14.0",
        "typescript": "latest"
    }
}

next.config.js:
// noinspection JSValidateTypes

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const { withPlugins, optional } = require('next-compose-plugins')
const nextConfig = {
    modularizeImports: {
        "@mui/material": {
            transform: "@mui/material/{{member}}",
        },
    },
    reactStrictMode: true,

    experimental: {
        output: 'standalone',
        // externalDir: true
    },
    eslint: {
        /**
         * Warning: Dangerously allow production builds to successfully complete even if
         * your project has ESLint errors.
         */
        ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
    },
    images: {
        disableStaticImages: true,
    },
    swcMinify: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_NODE_ENV === 'production',
    webpack: config => {
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.svg$/i,
            issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
            use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
        })

        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.(png|gif|svg)$/i,
            issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
                outputPath: 'static/images/',
            },
        })

        return config
    },
}

const noRecoilMessagesOnDevelopment = nextConfig => {
    if (process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_NODE_ENV === 'development') {
        require('intercept-stdout')(text => (text.includes('Duplicate atom key') ? '' : text))
    }
    return { ...nextConfig }
}

const plugins = [
    optional(() => {
        if (process.env.ANALYZE !== 'True') return {}
        return require('@next/bundle-analyzer')()
    }),
    noRecoilMessagesOnDevelopment,
]

module.exports = withPlugins(plugins, nextConfig)


Have you tried to add "use client" in the top of both files ?

just add "use client" at line 1 of both of your file

yes i add 'use client' on the top the the files, but i get the same error

To be honest with you, I'd use MUI Styled as recommended in the official documentation, rather than @emotion/styled

My problem was solved by add these lines to next.config.js:
 modularizeImports: {
        "@mui/material": {
            transform: "@mui/material/{{member}}",
        },
    },

